# libui - how to load icon from resource file?

Tags: c++, c

I am using libui (https://github.com/andlabs/libui) for simple GUI app and I want to set window icon from resource file (not portable, only for Windows).

If I add this line:

```
MAINICON ICON main.ico
```

to resources.rc, application will have main.ico as its icon, but this icon won't appears in window title or tray. Icon for window title is being set by

```
hDefaultIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
```

https://github.com/andlabs/libui/blob/17486fd17593510452939a120dc9a4e6fbe5cf80/windows/init.cpp#L76 - line 76

I need to do something like this:

```
hDefaultIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MAINICON));
```

but there is not generated resource.h with

```
#define MAINICON <some_number>
```

Does anybody know how to generate necessary header file or how to load icon from resource file?

Comment: You have not explained why you *have* to change this.  There is very little point to it, "IDI_APPLICATION" is boilerplate in most any app.  If you are going to change it then you do have to start editing.  Modify the library source code as you guessed.  And stick the MAINICON #define in a header file that the resource compiler can see.  Judging from the library's resources.rc file that should be resources.hpp.

Comment: **libui** is still in alpha state and it has no support for setting application icon (and icon in window title is hardcoded to "IDI_APPLICATION").